# How to detect combination of multiple modifier and non-modifier keys in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, key-events

I have tried different solutions given here for the question, but couldn't seem to get around it. I want to detect <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in a `KeyDown` event in VB.Net.

The `KeyPreview` property is set to true for my form.

What I tried is:

```
If e.Modifiers = (Keys.Shift And Keys.Control) And e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
    'do the action
End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `If e.Modifiers = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Control)...`  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs.Modifiers);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true) `To determine whether a specific modifier key was pressed, use the Control, Shift, and Alt properties. Modifier flags can be combined with bitwise OR.`

Answer (score 1):

The comment to your question is correct:

```
If (e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Shift)) Then
    'Do what you want here
End If
```

If you would like this to happen anywhere on your form, you need to put the `KeyPreview` of your `Form` to `True`.

You can then put it in the `Form_KeyDown`

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? I tested this by displaying a Message Box when these keys were pressed and it works. Would you like to see this code?

See edit RE: where to put code.