# How to detect multiple modifier buttons and character pressed in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, keydown

In a VB.NET project (working in VS2013) I need to do something when the user presses CTRL + LEFT SHIFT + M.

The closest I've gotten is to just be able to detect ONE of the modifier keys and the M key.

There is [this question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397987/how-to-detect-combination-of-multiple-modifier-and-non-modifier-keys-in-vb-net), but the only answer with sample code provided detects the character key and **one or the other** modifier keys, not both.

I've been hunting for a while now and the only examples I've seen show just one modifier key detected, I can't figure out how to detect two modifier keys and a character key.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso (e.KeyCode And Not Keys.Modifiers) = Keys.M Then
    HideForm()
End If
```

It looks like only one of the keys gets detected on the KeyDown event, which makes sense, I guess, since the event is going to fire separately for each of the keys.

So how do I detect when all three of the keys are pressed?

Comment: `If e.Control AndAlso e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.M Then`

Comment: Nope, didn't do it, Lars. :( In the KeyDown event it's only detecting the very first key that is pressed. So if I do CTRL + SHIFT + M it just gets CRTL (e.Control is true for your code), and if I do SHIFT + CTRL + M then it just gets the shift key (e.Shift is true).

Comment: Just to clarify: Its not possible to (meaningfully) debug the KeyDown Event Handler since it will break always on the first key press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ProcessCmdKey override on the form that you are using:

```vb
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  If keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Shift Or Keys.M) Then
    ' do something
    Return True
  End If
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: Bingo! That did it. Thanks, Lars.

Comment: I would appreciate any explanation why overriding ProcessCmdKey is necessary here and KeyDown/PreviewKeyDown is not working

Comment: @AlexB. ProcessCmdKey happens before anything else on the form.  Not sure why the KeyPreview = true didn't work for you, but KeyPreview was an old holdover from the VB6 days.

Comment: Dammit, I guess I forgot to tell @marky about setting KeyPreview=true ;) Thanks for clarification

Comment: I do have the form's KeyPreview property set to True, so like both of you, I'm not sure why the originally-suggested solution isn't working...